# tabs command in .profile, bash_profile prevents expect to run

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have written some script executable under root, where I need to `su - oracle` from root, then `source oraenv` and only then many other tasks follows. This is because all SIDs are running under oracle user, so the `source oraenv` asks for SID and then sets the environment for this particular SID.
For this I am using expect within my BASH script very often.
Everything went fine until the moment the script was used on a system where there is this headache stuff within oracle's .profile and/or .bash_profile:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/tabs ]
   then
   /usr/bin/tabs -8
fi
```

When making `su - oracle` as a user, new blank line shows upon login:

```
server:(/root)(root)#su - oracle
Last login: Tue May  2 12:52:01 CEST 2023

server:(/home/oracle)(oracle)#
```

But what is worst - this produces following crazy characters just before any expect procedure with input parameters when expect stuff is called from within the script - for example:

```
' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' $'\EH' /usr/local/bin/oraenv R01 check status params /tmp/tmp.hUQAUljWdy /tmp/tmp.toszCySPhv /var/opt/script.log /opt
```

The line calling this expect function should look like this, of course, to get all the parameters correctly:

```
/usr/local/bin/oraenv R01 check status params /tmp/tmp.hUQAUljWdy /tmp/tmp.toszCySPhv /var/opt/script.log /opt
```

I have started by trying to define prompt within expect somehow to tell expect that the prompt could be so crazy, but I was not successfull.
Then I have tried to get rid of those `tabs -8` lines from oracle .profile files (by replacing them with some echo to /dev/null) just before first expect is called from the script - to no avail. It seems like once the script starts, then when expect is called, the original .profile and/or bash_profile is source. This baffles me, because the script runs under the root user and switches under oracle later, only when needed. I have even tried to get rid of those tabs from profile files and do some 1st shot of expect with sourcing new profile files - so mimicking login to oracle user and thus source newly created .profile and bash_profile, but with the same results - crazy `?H` characters.

Have any of you needed to solve something similar?
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Probably a much better solution is to not have that command in your `.profile`, or guard it so it only runs when the shell is connected to a terminal.

Comment: @tripleee this is not possible, the solution is for the customer and the guys there simply have this setup...but not everywhere :-) so I have to respect both - tabs or not tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](https://espterm.github.io/docs/VT100%20escape%20codes.html), that's the VT100 escape sequence for setting a tab:

> ```
> tabset HTS            Set a tab at the current column        ^[H
> ```

The simplest mechanisms for working around this (as it appears to be difficult to get the target system to stop calling `/usr/bin/tabs` which is producing this output) is to either:

1. Set the `TERM` environment variable to `dumb` *prior* to `spawn`ing the `ssh` call. This *should* make `tabs` believe it can't do anything.

   ```
   set env(TERM) dumb
   spawn ssh ...
   ```
2. Adapt your expect script to ignore all that stuff; expect is far more powerful than:

   ```
   expect {
       -re {.*\eH} exp_continue
       "/usr/local/bin/oraenv"
   }
   ```

Hopefully you don't need to do both of these!

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. the first - in BATCH `export TERM=dumb` did not make any difference. The second proposal - as I understand it - tells expect not to bother with those crazy chars IF FOUND and just do what is needed. I assume that this should be in every send, spawn, expect line of whole expect procedure then, am I right?

Comment: I meant `in BASH` in previous comment, sorry

Comment: at least I have solved those crazy escape characters within root script. I have noticed that one of my variables for oraenv binary, which I am deriving by `su - ${ora_user} -c "which oraenv"` was actually filled up with blank line full of escape characters and the actual value in next line. I have got rid of this successfully, now I must tell expect which prompt to expect while exp_continue those escape chars, then define new prompt and perhaps it will go :-)

Comment: I am using expect from BASH script, so I called it like `expect -c "....."` . Thanks to your hints I have fixed it for now like this: immediately after `spawn su - $_ora_user` I am doing this `expect { -re {.*\eH} exp_continue -re {[#>$]} \"send \"export TERM=dumb\"\" }` . Then I do `expect \"\"` and then I set a new prompt `send \"PS1=\'>>\'\r\"` which I expect like `expect -re {>>$}` . What worries me is that on some servers the prompt is followed by space - i.e. I would need cover both `{[#>$]}` and `{[#>$] }` ....and I do not know why....

Answer (score 0):

Donald, thanks a lot for your tip.
The final solution is as follows now:

```
  expect -c "
  log_file $_LOG
  spawn su - $_ora_user
  expect {
      -re {.*\eH} exp_continue
      -re {[#>$]}
      \"send \"export TERM=dumb\"\"
  }
  expect \"\"
  send \"PS1=\'>>\'\r\"
  expect -re {>>$}
  send \"source $_oraenv_binary\r\"
  expect {ORACLE_SID = \[$_ora_user\] ? }
  send \"$_SID\r\"
  expect \"The Oracle base has been set to /oracle/$_SID\"
  expect -re {>>$}
  .....
  log_file
  exit [lindex \$result 0]"
```

This behaves as I wanted: when crazy characters of escape sequence from tabs command in .profile occur, then your regex helps expect to recognize it, and simply continue, which helps me then to `export TERM=dumb` which in turns gets rid of those escape sequence characters, so it is possible to set a new prompt and correctly do the rest.
As could be seen, if no escape chars happens, then spawning `su - $_ora_user` can result in plain `expect ""` which is the same as the result of `export TERM=dumb` - that is great, as the code covers then both situations.

Thanks again and wish you all well.